# Is Russian village named Rawaliszki in 1912 still there?

Tags: russia, historical-gazetteer, place-names, renaming-places

My Grand father immigrated to the USA in 1912. On his entry to Ellis Island on the manifest list he listed his ethnic background as Poland/Russia, and the village he was born in is listed as Rawaliszki. Russia.

In 1912 there is a village in Russia with that name, Checking further, that village no longer exist or changed its name or is no longer in Russian in modern time. How can I find out what the current village name is, and what country it's in?

Comment: How do you know thete's a village in Russia in 1912 with that name -- i.e. what sources have you consulted so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-to-find-current-name-or-location-of-russian-town-recorded-in-1910?rq=1

Comment: Villages and Maps - SGGEE
https://www.sggee.org/SGGEE2009/research/village_maps.html

Includes some detail maps as well, some of which cover the Suwalki region of ColeValleyGirl, I used this web site to acquire this information, Thanks for any help you may have--Tommy M.                                                                 Russian Poland. 3. Meyers Orts Leksicon is a German language town and village gazetteer, especially relevant to Prussian regions.
Images of 1900 polish/russian town/village of rawalizski